# LINQ Select min field value from multiple similar records in List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out how to do what I know in T-SQL as a group and aggregate process.

I have a `List<T>` and in that list I have 2 records of each instance. I need the record with the lower value.

So in application I have student records. So my list would be like this:

```
0    studentid 1    score 75.345
1    studentid 1    score 33.653
2    studentid 2    score 94.876
3    studentid 2    score 15.234
etc....
```

I have these records in a `List<Student>` result:

```
var result = abc.Find<Student>...snip
```

To be clear, the business rule says to find the lower score between the two.

So how would I accomplish this filtering and selection in Linq? I see there are Group and aggregate Linq extensions but honestly not sure if that is the route to pursue.

Comment: Are you saying you want the minimum score for each studentid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `GroupBy` and `Min` functions.

```
var result = context.GroupBy(s=> s.StudentId)
                    .Select(sg => new {
                                        StudentId = sg.Key, 
                                        MinScore = sg.Min(sc=> sc.Score)
                                      });
```

Comment: That should be something like `MinScore = sg.Min(s => s.Score)`.

Comment: yep, just fixed it

Comment: So in essence the same basic way I would in TSQL. Will accept in 4 more minutes. Thx

Comment: yep, exactly, you just have to know how `GroupBy` and `Min` work in linq

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s1=new Student(){Id=0, Name="Student 1", Score=56.44};
        var s2=new Student(){Id=1, Name="Student 1", Score=34.45};
        var s3=new Student(){Id=2, Name="Student 2", Score=56.23};
        var s4=new Student(){Id=3, Name="Student 2", Score=98.54};

    var list=new List<Student>(){s1,s2,s3,s4};

    var select=list.OrderBy(x=>x.Score).GroupBy(x=>x.Name);

    var newList=new List<Student>();

    foreach (var item in select){

        newList.Add(item.First());

    }

    foreach (var item in newList){

        Console.WriteLine(item.Id +"/"+item.Name +"/"+item.Score);
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Score {get;set;}
    }
  }
```

First you need to `order by` Score, then `group-by` name, then take `first` from each group.

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)